# Clustering Algorithm (in Python) for Data

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-computing

I have thousands of data entries that looks similar to the following:

```
08 00 00 00 c3 85 20 65 6e 61 62 6c 65 64 2e 0d 0a 45 78 70
5c 72 88 74 80 83 82 79 68 8d 7b 73 90 7c 60 84 80 74 00 00
5d 77 84 76 7d 85 7f 7d 6c 94 7e 73 82 74 61 7f 7b 76 00 00
63 70 84 8c 95 87 80 72 65 73 70 67 85 8a 64 93 89 74 00 00
65 7c 73 6c 6c 9a a2 86 7e 4f 7e 71 7c 79 5c 7f 72 7b 00 00
...
```

Each entry has 20 numbers, of which each number can be any value between 0 and 255 (shown as a hex number).  I have references that I can use to help pin the clusters.  The references have the same template as the data.

I have already determined that I can use a Manhattan distance equation to give each one a numerical value with regard to a reference array.  But I'm looking for a way to cluster the data.  Based on what I know about the data, there should be approximately 50-60 clusters.  I expect some of the data to be outside of a threshold and consequently not apart of any cluster.

With the way that the data is setup, I can process the data as it comes in (about once 20 seconds).  I haven't found a convenient library to use and the entire thing must be written in python (preferably with just the standard library).

I was hoping that I did not need to develop the algorithm on my own.  I believe I might want a MinHash, but I am open to other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

So, it really depends on what kind of clustering you want. Clustering is an incredibly large and generally quite quantitatively-expensive operation and there are a large number of different approaches to it.

I would go as far to say that there is no better solution to your problem than using scikit's clustering modules. They have a fantastic breakdown of their different clustering algorithms shown here: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html

Personally I use DBSCAN for most applications, but depending on exactly how you want to cluster this data that might not be the best choice for you. Also worth mentioning that Manhattan Distance is usually not a great choice for clustering algorithms and cosine distance and euclidean distance can both be more performant and give a more accurate representation of your data.

Comment: My issue with scipy is that it requires compilation.  I'm using an arm processor and I do not have access to the toolset to create a new library.  Hence the preference for a standard library implementation.  Every extra calculation counts on my system.  So an extra step to calculate power along with a square root is noticeable.

Comment: Scipy and related libraries can definietely be run on an ARM processor, though the SSE optimization breaks down. If you add a bit more about your use case I could add to this to help you out.

Comment: It's an ARM926EJ-Sid(wb) rev 4 (v5l) (/proc/cpuinfo), and I am running a uclibc version of Linux (kernel: 2.6.8-rc2-fs3). I am also on Python 2.5.

Comment: If you've got uclibc linux up, the clustering module is old enough that you should just be able to get pre-compiled binaries through rpm.

Comment: I will look.  So far, any binaries I have found have the wrong ABI.  Back in gcc 3.x, GCC moved from OABI to EABI.  All binaries produced prior to gcc 3.x needed to be recreated.  In addition, any new binaries produced with gcc 3.x or higher will not work on the older gcc 2.x.  All of my builds are produced with gcc 2.x

Answer (score -1):

A quick Google search reveals the python-cluster package, located at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cluster/1.1.0b1.  One of the examples shows something I believe to be somewhat similar to the data setup that you want.  The package does advise for large datasets to perform the clustering in a separate thread, though I believe in your specific situation that wouldn't be necessary.

```
>>> from cluster import *
>>> data = [12,34,23,32,46,96,13]
>>> cl = HierarchicalClustering(data, lambda x,y: abs(x-y))
>>> cl.getlevel(10)     # get clusters of items closer than 10
[96, 46, [12, 13, 23, 34, 32]]
>>> cl.getlevel(5)      # get clusters of items closer than 5
[96, 46, [12, 13], 23, [34, 32]]
```

Because you know all your data is between 0 and 255, the `getlevel(5)` call would separate your data into approximately 50-52 clusters.  Also, you would have to convert your dataset into a list of integers.

**Edit:** Turns out, that won't do what you want.  I assume you have enough data that you'll have at least one value for every five.  This clustering algorithm will just group everything into a big nested list, as below.

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> x = HierarchicalClustering(data, lambda x,y: abs(x-y))
>>> x.getlevel(1)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  My understanding is that the hierarchical clustering methods are not as performant as the MinHash.  However, I do like this package.